Flutter MQTT client certificate error TLSV1_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED
I have a flutter mobile application that needs to connect to MQTT broker. Connection is tested with another client with same certificates and it works as expected.
I am using newest MQTT client package
Here is my Flutter code:
Future connect() async {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContext.defaultContext;

    // Load certificate
    ByteData certificateData = await rootBundle.load('assets/clientcert.pem');
    List<int> certificateBytes = certificateData.buffer.asUint8List();
    context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(certificateBytes);

    // Load private key
    ByteData privateKeyData = await rootBundle.load('assets/clientkey.pem');
    List<int> privateKeyBytes = privateKeyData.buffer.asUint8List();
    context.usePrivateKeyBytes(privateKeyBytes);

    MqttServerClient client = MqttServerClient.withPort(
      'mqtt.my.client',
      'flutter_client',
      8883,
    );
    client.onBadCertificate = badCertificateCallback;
    client.securityContext = context;
    client.onConnected = () => print("MQTT > CONNECTED");
    client.onDisconnected = () => print("MQTT > DISCONNECTED");
    client.secure = true;
    client.setProtocolV311();
    client.logging(on: true);

    return await client.connect().onError((error, stackTrace) {
      print(error);
    });
  }

After running this, I get the following:
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.625116 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - secure selected
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.625302 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - calling connect
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.625452 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - entered
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.711946 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - securing socket
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.712515 -- MqttSecureConnection::connect - start listening
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.712794 -- MqttServerConnection::_startListening
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.713357 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - connection complete
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.713623 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect sending connect message
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.713847 -- MqttConnectionHandlerBase::sendMessage - MQTTMessage of type MqttMessageType.connect
I/flutter (18726): Header: MessageType = MqttMessageType.connect, Duplicate = false, Retain = false, Qos = MqttQos.atMostOnce, Size = 26
I/flutter (18726): Connect Variable Header: ProtocolName=MQTT, ProtocolVersion=4, ConnectFlags=Connect Flags: Reserved1=false, CleanStart=true, WillFlag=false, WillQos=MqttQos.atMostOnce, WillRetain=false, PasswordFlag=false, UserNameFlag=false, KeepAlive=0
I/flutter (18726): MqttConnectPayload - client identifier is : flutter_client
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.715438 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - pre sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:22.747042 -- MqttConnectionBase::_onError - calling disconnected callback
E/flutter (18726): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: TlsException: 
E/flutter (18726):  TLSV1_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED(tls_record.cc:592) error 268436572
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:27.718263 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect - post sleep, state = Connection status is connecting with return code of noneSpecified and a disconnection origin of none
I/flutter (18726): 1-2024-04-09 14:13:27.719450 -- SynchronousMqttServerConnectionHandler::internalConnect failed
I/flutter (18726): mqtt-client::NoConnectionException: The maximum allowed connection attempts ({3}) were exceeded. The broker is not responding to the connection request message (Missing Connection Acknowledgement?

Desperately looking for any solution or tips, thank you.

You appear to be setting a CA bundle and a Client Private key, but no actual Client cert. The file name you pass as the CA bundle looks like it should be used as the Client cert not the CA bundle...

@hardillb sorry, I think I was messing with code and didn't revert. I edited the code with a use of setTrustedCertificatesBytes but it still produces the same error

Maybe you need both, is your broker cert signed by the same CA as the client cert or a public CA?
